I'm given a dictionary and asked to find the frequency of terms above a certain threshold in each index without using sum, len, or count functions
I'm given a dictionary and asked to use functions and equations to calculate the frequency of items that fall into a certain threshold without using sum, len, or count, and without importing numpy or other programs. I keep running into problems when I go to print my results, with terms not being defined. I have a very poor handle on functions so I apologize for that.
The dictionary is given as
observation = {'temperature': [85, 90, 15, 25, 90, 11, 20, 15, 25],
           'dewpoint': [80, 85, 10, 20, 85, 8, 15, 15, 22],
           'wind speed': [5, 10, 2, 0, 25, 30, 35, 4, 2],
           'precipitation': [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3]}

and asked to print out "temperature exceeded 50 3 times" and so on for each index.
I've got the following code so far:
def temp_freq():

    exceedances = 0 

    threshold = 50

    for value in observation['temperature']:
        if value > threshold:
            exceedances += 1
   
    return exceedances

print(f"temperature exceeded {threshold} {temp_freq(exceedances):.1f} times")

And I keep getting errors about defining terms within the print statement
Errors:
NameError: name 'threshold' is not defined

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include whatever errors you get in your post.  Although a quick skim of your code, your temp_freq() function doesn't have any parameters, so it isn't clear why you're providing exceedances to it.

thanks, I still get this error even if I put 'def temp_freq(threshold, exceedances):'

@user28135631 Move the line threshold = 50 out of the function so it is available globally. Also call the function like this: temp_func().

You got the error Error: name 'threshold' is not defined because threshold (and also exceedances) are out of the scope where you're using them. They exist only locally during the execution of function temp_freq():
You could take both constants out of the function as I've done so below, or send them as parameters to the function.
def temp_freq(threshold, exceedances):


    for value in observation['temperature']:
        if value > threshold:
            exceedances += 1
   
    return exceedances 


exceedances = 0 
threshold = 50

print(f"temperature exceeded {threshold} {temp_freq(threshold, exceedances):.1f} times")


Unfortunately that doesn't work because now the for and return functions are outside of the scope of the function

Oh sorry, i didn't know hot to ident the code answer! but with that, the problem you mention will get solved
upd- fixed. Tks!
